# Can't delete a file as administrator

Tags: windows, administrator

I started file explorer as admin I tried deleting it from elevated command prompt nothing works.

Security tab only shows this:

[image]

Even after clicking the button with a shield.

I have wsl installed on this PC but same story if I try to access it from there.

I can see the following through bash with ls -la on the file:

[image]

When I try to add this to the parent instead with "Replace all child object permission entries..." it says this:

[image]

Comment: In order to delete a file, even as an Administrator, the file must be owned by the user or the user group the Administrator assigned to.

Comment: Your administrator user absolutely is NOT the owner of that particular folder.  **The SYSTEM user is the owner of that particular folder.** In order to change the permissions of that folder you will have to change the owner.  However, if this folder belongs to WSL, you absolutely DO NOT WANT TO DO THAT.

Comment: The change button shows me the first screenshot in my question

Comment: Did you install npm within WSL?  It seems like that might be the case.  Instead of trying to delete the folder Ionic, change the owner of the folder, using that elevated command prompt using that command I provided.  If it's successful it will indicate the folder has a new owner.  If you installed NPM within WSL, the command will fail, for obvious reasons.  You would have to shutdown the WSL or uninstall it through WSL.

Comment: Sounds like you have some work to do in order to understand what is or isn't installed on your system.  Be sure you [edit] your question so your problem can be properly diangnosed.

Comment: npm cache clean -f and afterwards uninstalling NodeJS worked! Now I'm getting NVM instead..

Answer (score 0):

For many files associated with programs, the SYSTEM user is the owner.
It's not usually a good idea to change that either because they are usually associated with protected files.
Often times there is an uninstaller prepackaged that can achieve the end goal so you don't have to goof around with the permissions, that's where I would start.